# Is stdin,0,STDIN are different things

Tags: c, unix

Is stdin is a pointer, as I have seen its usage in fgets().

I used '0' as we use for read or write mistakenly for stdin and got a segfault during fgets.

Is STDIN macro and 0 are the same.

Is stdin is a file pointer. Please explain about this

Comment: **man 3 stdin**: `extern FILE *stdin;`

Comment: You also got a compiler warning that you completely ignored. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Will go through the man pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdin` is a macro that expands to an expression of type `FILE *` (so, yes, it is a pointer).  Its value is unspecified, but it is required to point to a concrete object, so it is definitely non-NULL.
`0` is an integer constant, which converts to a NULL pointer when used in pointer context.  It follows that `stdin != 0`.
`STDIN` is not defined by the standard C library.

You may have heard that the OS-level *file descriptor* corresponding to `stdin` has the value 0, which is true, but file descriptors and `FILE` objects are not the same thing, and they cannot be used interchangeably.  (If you're on a Unixy system, read `/usr/include/stdio.h` sometime.  It's "just" more C.  Usually there is a concrete definition of the `FILE` object in there, as a fairly complicated `struct`, even though this is not required by the standard.)

Comment: That was a good explanation Zack. Thanks for helping me understand the difference.

Answer (score 5):

stdin is a `FILE *` from `stdio.h`

```
STDIN_FILENO == fileno(stdin)
```

`STDIN_FILENO` is in `unistd.h` and is used for functions like `write`, whereas stdin as a File * is used for stdio functions like `printf`

Comment: Thanks Max for helping to understand.